# How to open a new jFrame with denied access to the previous jFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I want to open a new jFrame by clicking a button in another, while blocking the access to that jFrame. That means....like in message boxes.when a message box opened by clicking a button in a jFrame, we cant access the jframe anymore until we close the message box.if we try to click on the jframe there it makes a beep noise that reminds us there is a message box opened.
Likewise I need to do this to a new jFrame.when a new jFrame opens by clicking a button on the previous jFrame,the previous frame should not be accessed anymore(should not be closed) until I close the newly opened frame. How can I do this.Is there any simple change in the property of the jframe in Netbeans(without writing codes).

Comment: You should consider to use [Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html)

Comment: No, don't "consider" using dialogs -- **use** them as what you're describing is precisely the behavior of *modal* dialogs. Also, if you're creating classes that extend JFrame, don't as that paints you into a corner. Instead gear your classes towards creating JPanels which can be placed anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`JFrame` doesn't have that feature. You'll have to use `JDialog` instead.

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(otherFrame , true);

...//do some other stuff

dialog.setVisible(true);
```